# Exclude Numerous Values for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently still learning SQL, however, I can't seem to actually find out how to `exclude` multiple usernames.

Example I have 2 columns at hand, 1 being username and another having the state of active or not.

```
UserName Status
===============
ABC           Y
CDE           Y
FGH           Y
IJK           Y
LMN           Y
OPQ           Y
QRS           Y
```

and the list goes on. Example if I wanted to change the entire status from Y to N, the query would be similar to this.

```
update database
set status = 'N'
```

However if I want to add numerous values, I'm not sure how to query it out.

```
update database
set status = 'N' 
where (username != 'ABC' or username != 'DEF')
```

would be great if someone could teach and explain step by step cause I can't seem to understand how people use specific functions such as t1 and t2 to solve this and group by as well.

Comment: Whats wrong with your second query. It will exclude username `ABC` and `DEF` and update the remaining rows to `N`. Also what do you mean by **However if i want to add numerous values**. You second query can rewritten by using `NOT IN` operator

Comment: _" i can't seem to understand how people use specific functions such as t1 and t2 to solve this and group by as well"_ I don't understand what you mean by this, could you clarify it?

Comment: t1 and t2? Can't see where group by would come in in your example either.

Comment: hi guys, thanks for the replies, i went through quite a number of threads and it seems that most answers require having t1 and t2 therefore i came up with the assumption that it requires having the t1 and t2 theory before it could work, but it seems that i didn't know about the        `not in`.    operator so i'm gonna try that out and see if it works. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like NoDisplayName mentions in the latter part of his comment,

Use of NOT IN is your WHERE clause is the one required to exclude mutliple values. Like this :

```
update database
    set status = 'N' 
    where username NOT IN ('ABC', 'CDE', 'XYZ')
```

If the values are to be drawn from a table/recordset based on some criterion you can use a select query after NOT IN instead of a list of values.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for thanks! I did not know of the `NOT IN`. command on MSSQL, i may have overlooked it. thanks a lot for the help!